# Calling C function from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, pointers

I am trying to call a C function from Swift , but I do not know exactly how to define variables to pass parameters.

The function c is:

```
DBFGetFieldInfo( DBFHandle psDBF, int iField, char * pszFieldName, int * pnWidth, int * pnDecimals );
```

The main problem is `pszFieldName`, `pnWidth` and `pnDecimals` inout parameters. I tried made ​​:

```
var dbf:DBFHandle = DBFOpen(pszPath, "rb")
var fName:[CChar] = [] 
var fieldWidth:Int32 = 0
let fieldDecimals:Int32 = 0

let fieldInfo:DBFFieldType = DBFGetFieldInfo(dbf, i, fName, &fieldWidth, &fieldDecimals)
```

but it gives me an error

```
Cannot invoke 'DBFGetFieldInfo' with an argument list of type '(DBFHandle, Int32, [CChar], inout Int32, inout Int32)'
Expected an argument list of type '(DBFHandle, Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>)'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>
```

You need to convert your variables to the appropriate types required by the method signature.

C Syntax:

- const Type *
- Type *

Swift Syntax:

- UnsafePointer
- UnsafeMutablePointer

This is covered by Apple in their Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C reference [located here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).

Answer (score 0):

**C Syntax  ----->  Swift Syntax**

const Type *  ----->           UnsafePointer

Type *   ----->                UnsafeMutablePointer

The number of input and the types should be the same

Answer (score 0):

To create an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` from a string use:

```
String(count: 10, repeatedValue: Character("\0")).withCString( { cString in
    println()
    // Call your function here with cString
})
```

Comment: In your code sample, `cString` is a `UnsafePointer<Int8>`, **not** a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`.